# is there any method to add float field in laravel backpack

Tags: database, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I am writing a min laravel project using backpack-crud.Database table want to receive float number but laravel backpack does not support float field .

I want to add float number into database table from input.

please share your thoughts.

Comment: https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-number
do you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[   // Number
    'name' => 'number',
    'label' => 'Number',
    'type' => 'number',
    // optionals
    // 'attributes' => ["step" => "any"], // allow decimals
    // 'prefix' => "$",
    // 'suffix' => ".00",
],
```

May be this will help you. reference: https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-number